# Mono FM radio demodulation

Tags: python, frequency-modulation

I am trying to demodulate an IQ file containing a sample of a FM radio signal using two methods.  First, I tried reading the whole file and demodulate all data at the same time.  Second, I tried reading a block of data and demodulate each block as I received it, simulating the data streaming in from an Software Defined Radio.

The first method works fine.  Below is the code I for it:

```
# importing libraries
import os
import pathlib
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# Parameters
Fs = 2.4e6  # Sample rate

data_decimate_factor = 10
audio_decimate_factor = 5

filepath = os.path.join(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()), 'fm_iq_2400k_complex2')

# Demodulating FM signal by reading whole file
try:
    with open(filepath,'rb') as fid:
        with open("wbfm-mono.raw",'ab') as fid_audio:
            # Get data
            data = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.complex64)

            dat_decimated = signal.decimate(data, data_decimate_factor, ftype='fir', zero_phase=True)

            # Demodulate FM signal
            dat_demod = np.angle(dat_decimated[1:] * np.conj(dat_decimated[:-1]))

            # Pass data through the de-emphasis filter
            bz, az = signal.bilinear(1, [75e-6, 1], fs=Fs)
            dat_deemphasis = signal.lfilter(bz, az, dat_demod)

            audioDataLplusR = dat_deemphasis[::audio_decimate_factor]

            # Scale so it's audible
            audioDataLplusR *= 10000 / np.max(np.abs(audioDataLplusR))

            # Save audio to file
            fid_audio.write(audioDataLplusR.astype(np.int16))

except Exception as e:
    print(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))
```

The second method works, but there are clicks and pops noise in the audio.  Here's the code for it:

```
# importing libraries
import os
import pathlib
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

# Parameters
Fs = 2.4e6  # Sample rate
N = 1024*1000    # Number of sample points

data_decimate_factor = 10
audio_decimate_factor = 5

filepath = os.path.join(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()), 'fm_iq_2400k_complex2')

# Demodulating FM signal by reading blocks of data
try:
    with open(filepath,'rb') as fid:
        with open("wbfm-mono.raw",'ab') as fid_audio:
            while (1):
                # Get data
                data = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.complex64, count=N)

                if (len(data) <= 0):
                    break;

                dat_decimated = signal.decimate(data, data_decimate_factor, ftype='fir', zero_phase=True)

                # Demodulate FM signal
                dat_demod = np.angle(dat_decimated[1:] * np.conj(dat_decimated[:-1]))

                # Pass data through the de-emphasis filter
                bz, az = signal.bilinear(1, [75e-6, 1], fs=Fs)
                dat_deemphasis = signal.lfilter(bz, az, dat_demod)

                audioDataLplusR = dat_deemphasis[::audio_decimate_factor]

                # Scale so it's audible
                audioDataLplusR *= 10000 / np.max(np.abs(audioDataLplusR))

                # Save audio to file
                fid_audio.write(audioDataLplusR.astype(np.int16))

except Exception as e:
    print(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))
```

I am using almost exactly the same code for both methods, but I do not understand why there's noise in the second method.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?  Also, if there's a better way to demodulate FM radio signal, please let me know.

Comment: Try saving the state of the filters in your main loop -- the details are in SciPy's documentation.

Comment: You're right.  Saving the state for the deemphasis filter solves the problem.  Thanks